# How to click Checkbox inside ng-repeat table using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, checkbox, angularjs-ng-repeat, ui-automation

I am automating a web application using Selenium Java, this web application has angular js ng-repeat table as below which creates row with checkbox inside each row. I need to select few checkbox based on condition to test.

I am using below code to find these checkbox but unable to find and click.

```
    // To locate table.
    WebElement mytable = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class='table']/tbody"));
    // To locate rows of table.
    List<WebElement> rows_table = mytable.findElements(By.id("check"));
    // To calculate no of rows In table.
    int rows_count = rows_table.size();
    System.out.println(rows_count);
```

Webpage source looks like below

```
`<table class="table" ng-cloak> 
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="C orderBy : colsort:reverseSort">
<td>
<input id="check" type="checkbox" ng-checked="C.Addc" ng-model="C.Addc" ng-    click="FindMsg(C.Addc,C.MSG)" />
</td>
<td>
{{C.ItemCode}}
</td>
<td>
{{C.Code}}
</td>
<td title="{{C.LongDescription}}">
{{C.LongDescription.substr(0,30)}}...
</td>
<td style="width: 40px; text-align: right">
{{formattingEnd(C.Enduserprice)}}
</td>
<td>
{{C.type}}
</td>
<td>
{{C.statusflag.toUpperCase}}
</td>
<td>
{{C.SInstType}}
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>`
```

Comment: Where is the code which you use to click? What is the element with `id="checkCPE"`?

Comment: first I am trying to identify the checkboxs and count with below code. but it is returning 0.

id="check" is the checkbox repeated in each row of table. <<>>

List<WebElement> rows_table = mytable.findElements(By.id("check"));

Comment: Check if there are more than one tables on page and if your table located inside `iframe`/`frame`

Answer (score 0):

ngWebDriver worked like a charm.

`ngWebDriver = new NgWebDriver((JavascriptExecutor) driver);
ngWebDriver.waitForAngularRequestsToFinish();
List<WebElement> wes = driver.findElements(ByAngular.repeater("C in SearchCPE"));
System.out.println("Row Count is : "+wes.size());`